# Webbrowser control document to fill form with button

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I know this is a similar question to others out there but I just can't get mine to work.

I have a login form I am trying to auto fill in a webbrowser control.

I want it to be able to fill the form from strings that are set from 2 listboxes when a button is clicked on the form outside the webbrowser.

Here is what I have so far but it does nothing on the browser control when I click it.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string user = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
       string pw = listBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
       webBrowers1.Navigate("http://xxxxxxx.com/");
       System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document = this.webBrowser1.Document;
       document.All["username"].SetAttribute("value", user);
       document.All["password"].SetAttribute("value", pw);

        HtmlElementCollection el2 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
        foreach (HtmlElement btn in el2)
        {
            if (btn.InnerText == "Sign in")
            {
                btn.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
    }
```

I must be missing something but cannot figure it out!  Thanks for any help

Comment: `Navigate()` is asynchronous, the document cannot be modified until its loaded so put your code into the `DocumentCompleted` event.

Comment: How do I pass the strings from the button click to the document complete event?

Comment: You don't you read them as you currently are; move any code that deals with the document into the new event

Comment: Dang!  Knew it had to be something simple.  Appreciate your help!